# Dynamic location block variable to string

Tags: nginx

I am trying to generate a single nginx `location` block that dymically changes depending on a captured matching location

```sh
location ~*\/(\w+)/archive {   
  fancyindex_footer "/fancyindex/footer-{$1}.html";
}
```

So if the location is `/something/archive` I want the string to say `/fancyindex/footer-something.html`

It's a simple request but I'm struggling to get it done or even being able to debug

Comment: Are you sure the `fancyindex_footer` directive accept variables as a part of its parameter? Did you try a static filename for debugging?

Comment: The static string works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've made some testing. Indeed, the `fancyindex_footer` directive can't interpolate variables from its parameter. Most likely the reason is that it is based on `add_after_body` directive from the [`ngx_http_addition_module`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_addition_module.html), and that one can't do it too. However using a [named capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) the following workaround should work:

```
location ~* /(?<idx>\w+)/archive {
    # by using a named capture group, we make our prefix to be captured with the
    # '$idx' variable rather than '$1' one, to be used later in the other location
    add_after_body /fancyindex/;
    # '/fancyindex/` string treated as a subrequest URI
}

location /fancyindex/ {
    # don't allow external access, use only as internal location
    internal;
    # use the full path to the 'fancyindex' folder as a root here
    root /full/path/to/fancyindex;
    # rewrite any URI to the '/footer-$idx.html' and serve it as a footer file
    rewrite ^ /footer-$idx.html break;
}
```

If I misunderstood your question and you just want to append a `/fancyindex/footer-something.html` string to your output instead of `/fancyindex/footer-something.html` file contents, change the internal location to

```
location /fancyindex/ {
    internal;
    return 200 "/fancyindex/footer-$idx.html";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying this out, I actually want the fancyindex to load `fancyindex_footer`, by using your second option it just prints "/fancyindex/footer-placeholder.html"; to the file, but I want to render the html not just put it as a string

Comment: Than what's wrong with the first example? It should do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Hold on, you are right, I added the full root path to `fancyindex` and then it worked. Many thanks!